# Hiding column in Power BI live connection

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular, msbi

i build power bi dashboard with live connection, but in power bi desktop all columns from fact table are visible, is there any option to hide columns when using live connection in power BI?

Comment: What system are you connecting to? AAS? SSAS? Power BI Dataset? There isn't a way to change the model from power bi desktop side, but there might be a way to hide on the source depending on the source capabilities

Comment: i am using SSAS tabular connection , and i have hidden my fact table in my model but still it is visible in power BI desktop

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in a Power BI Live Connection, it sees what is available in the SSAS cube and displays it. What you can do in SSAS is create a [Perspective](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/perspectives-ssas-tabular) that will limit the tables, columns and measures to what you want to select.

Hope that helps point you in the right direction

Comment: I just want to hide surrogate keys from fact table, "hide from client tools" is working in excel but not in power bi , just wanted to confirm perspective is the only way or any other way to do this?

Comment: if the Hide from client tools isn't working, the only method is to use a perspective.